# Internet Explorer 8 rendering HTML markup differently to other browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer-8

Below is the markup i have in my code. It works fine in all browsers except IE8.

```
<label>this is a label</label>
<input type="text" class="formTxt" />
<div class="fl">
    <select><option>opt 1</option><option>opt 2</option></select>
</div>
<div class="validationMsg">there has been an error!</div>
```

When viewed in IE8, the validation message is placed inbetween the two inputs. So i end up with them stacked on top of each other in the following order; input, validation message, then select menu. The code is rendered as follows in the DOM:

```
<label>this is a label</label>
<input type="text" class="" />
<div class="validationMsg">there has been an error!</div>
<div class="fl">
    <select><option>opt 1</option><option>opt 2</option></select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 label {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  padding: 4px 0;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .formTxt {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 4px;
 }

 input {
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
 }

 .inputSmall {
  width: 110px;
 }

 .fl {
  float: left;
 }

 .validationMsg{
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 0.3em 0 0;
  line-height: 1.3em;
 }
```

Can anyone help to why it is doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Seems fine to me using IE10 in Browser Mode IE8 with Document Mode in IE8 standards. Maybe there's something in the CSS that's doing weird stuff - you haven't shown that.

Comment: The HTML posted surely does not cause the effect. And the question is tagged with “css”, too – but no CSS code is disclosed. Besides, in situations like this, JavaScript is usually involved.

Comment: It looks like something with CSS or quirks mode. We need full code.

Comment: That's because it's Internet Explorer 8. If you can show your CSS then maybe we can help.

Comment: Very likely to be related to your CSS code, so you will need to post that in order to get any help.

Comment: sorry guys, added css now